# Ordenação de vetores de string e numeros

Tags: string, matriz, classificação, array

estou com um problema em um exercicio da facul.
Basicamente é um sistema de loja, onde eu entro com a quantidade de lojas, a quantidade de produtos, o nome dos produtos, e a quantidade de produtos em cada loja.
Até aqui tudo bem, o meu problema esta no fato de que eu tenho que imprimir a matriz que contem os produtos em ordem alfabética, ou seja, preciso criar uma função que ordene um vetor de strings, e não somente isso, também tenho que mudar a matriz com as quantidades de produtos assim como mudo o nome dos produtos, se não ficarei com os nomes em ordem mas as quantidades dos produtos erradas.
Minha idéia seria percorrer a matriz de strings e identificar em qual posição estão os menores elementos em ordem crescente e adicionar seus indices em uma matriz auxiliar, para que depois na hora de imprimir a matriz com os nomes e com os produtos eu siga os indices dessa matriz auxiliar, e não de um for, por exemplo:

```
matrizNome[0] = macarrao
matrizNome[1] = alface
matrizNome[2] = cebola
matrizNome[3] = batata
```

Criando a matriz auxiliar e salvando os indices da matrizNome, dessa maneira:

```
matrizAux[0] = 1
matrizAux[1] = 3
matrizAux[2] = 2
matrizAux[3] = 0
```

E então, quando for imprimir, uso os valores contidos na matrizAux:

```
for(i = 0; i < tamanho; i++){

    aux = matrizAux[i];
    printf("%d", matrizNome[aux]);
```

Mas ainda não consegui pensar em como fazer isso, vou deixa o meu codigo aqui em baixo e se caso puderem me ajudar, ficarei muito agradecido.

```
int ordena(char **matrizNome, int prod){

int i, j, k, auxnum;
int *vet = (int *) malloc (prod * sizeof(int));
char *aux[20];

for(i = 0; i < prod; i++){

    strcpy(aux, matrizNome[i]);

    for(j = i+1 ; j < prod; j++){

        k = strcmp(aux, matrizNome[j]);

    }
}
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

int prod; //Numero de colunas
int loja; //Numero de linhas
int i, j, k, nprod, nloja, prodLoja;
int **matriz = NULL, *vet;
char **matrizNome = NULL;
char produto[20];
int tamanho;

printf("Insira a quantidade de lojas: "); //Recebe a quantidade de lojas
scanf("%d", &loja);

printf("Insira a quantidade de produtos: "); //Recebe a quantidade de produtos
scanf("%d", &prod);

matriz = (int **) malloc (prod * sizeof(int)); //Inicia a matriz com prod colunas
for(i = 0; i < prod; i++){
    matriz[i] = (int *) malloc (loja * sizeof(int));
}

matrizNome = (char **) malloc (prod * sizeof(char));

printf("\n");
gets(produto);

for(i = 0; i < prod; i++){

    printf("Insira o nome do produto %d: ", i + 1);
    gets(produto);
    matrizNome[i] = (char *) malloc (30 * sizeof(char)+1);
    strcpy(matrizNome[i], produto);
}

//Entra com os valores na matriz [produto][loja]
for(i = 0; i < prod; i++){

    for(j = 0; j < loja; j++){

        printf("Insira a quantidade de itens %d na loja %d: ", i+1, j+1);
        scanf("%d", &matriz[i][j]);
    }
}

//Pula uma linha e escreve LOJA
printf("\nLoja:");

//Imprime a quantidade de lojas
for(k = 0; k < loja; k++){

    if(k == 0){
        printf("\t\t%d", k+1); //Dois tabs depois de imprimir loja
    }
    else{
        printf("\t%d", k+1); //Um tab depois do 1
    }
}

//Imprime um pulo de linha
printf("\n");

//Imprime a matriz para o usuario
for(i = 0; i < prod; i++){

    printf("\n%s", matrizNome[i]);
    tamanho = strlen(matrizNome[i]);

    if(tamanho < 8){
        printf("\t");
    }

    for(j = 0; j < loja; j++){

        printf("\t%d", matriz[i][j]);
    }
}

//Imprime um pulo de linha
printf("\n");

 //Libera a memoria Heap onde a matriz estava armazenada
for(i = 0; i < prod; i++) free(matriz[i]);
free (matriz);
for(i = 0; i < prod; i++) free(matrizNome[i]);
free (matrizNome);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nick, acredito que usando várias matrizes voce acabe usando a mesma quantidade de memória (ou mais até) que se usasse uma unica matriz com o nome e as quantidades, separadas por um "separador".

Algo como:

```
 matrizNome[0] = macarrao|0001|R$ 23,00
 matrizNome[1] = alface|0202|R$ 44,00
 matrizNome[2] = cebola|0051|R$ 3,00
 matrizNome[3] = batata|0002|R$ 11,00
```

Assim sendo, voce teria uma matriz de produtos, seu "indice" (que pode servir a outros propósitos) e seu preço unitário.

Ao imprimir esta matriz, bastaria voce efetuar um SORT nela ou fazer o SORT para uma nova matriz. Obviamente que voce pode ainda ter matrizes de produtos diferentes para diferentes tipos de alimentos (verduras, legumes, frutas).

Se pensar que suas linhas podem ser as acima, verá que conter uma matriz indexadora de ordem alfabética é apenas criar mais demanda de memória, sem necessidade.

MAS, seguindo o que voce deseja, penso que efetuar apenas um Bubble-Sort em sua matriz de nomes já executa o que deseja - ou seja, a matriz será sorteada sempre que for imprimi-la, o que não deverá criar demanda de CPU se for usando um bom algoritmo de SORT.

Consulte no Google sobre SORT STRING ALGORITHMS e verá coisas muito boas...

Espero ter ajudado.